# What is the diff between normal file upload and create thumbnails of an images using mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, image

Hi i am totally confused with file uploading. First of all any one explain me what is the difference between normal file uplaod and create thumbnail for image and save that path in db.

I checked the path of both normal and thumbnail. Moreover same only but i donno what is the differene between these two types of uplaod?.Can any one explain me these difference?

I tried both types. I paste that code here and any one tell me the difference between two types.

**1) Normal Uplaod using AJAX**

**View**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "FileUpload";
}

 <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" />
  <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload Files" />
  </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnUpload').click(function () {

        // Checking whether FormData is available in browser
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {

            var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;

            // Create FormData object
            var fileData = new FormData();

            // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }

            // Adding one more key to FormData object
            fileData.append('username', 'Manas');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/ImageUplaod/UploadFiles',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                processData: false, // Not to process data
                data: fileData,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("FormData is not supported.");
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
     public ActionResult  FileUpload()
    {
        return View();
    }

     [HttpPost]  
   public ActionResult UploadFiles()  
   {  
     // Checking no of files injected in Request object  
   if (Request.Files.Count > 0)  
    {  
    try  
    {  
        //  Get all files from Request object  
        HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;  
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)  
        {  
            //string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/";  
            //string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);  

            HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];  
            string fname;  

            // Checking for Internet Explorer  
            if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")  
            {  
                string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });  
                fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                fname = file.FileName;  
            }  

            // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
            fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);  
            file.SaveAs(fname);
            var imageupload = new imageupload();
            imageupload.ImageUplaod = fname;
            db.imageuploads.Add(imageupload);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }  
        // Returns message that successfully uploaded  
        return Json("File Uploaded Successfully!");  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);  
    }  
    }  
  else  
   {  
    return Json("No files selected.");  
   }  
  }
```

**2) Craete Thumbnails for image using MVC and save that path in db**

**Model**

```
public class ImageUploadModels
{

    [Key]  
public int ImgageID   
{  
    get;  
    set;  
}  
[Required]  
public string ImagePath   
{  
    get;  
    set;  
}  
}
```

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]  
   public ActionResult ImageUploadThumnail(ImageUploadModels image, HttpPostedFileBase file)   
   {  
    try {  
    if (file != null)  
    {  
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
        var thumbName = fileName.Split('.').ElementAt(0) + "_thumb." + fileName.Split('.').ElementAt(1);  
        fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images"), fileName);  
        thumbName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images"), thumbName);  
        image.ImagePath = fileName; //to store into database, if we use DbContext  
        file.SaveAs(fileName);  
        Image img = Image.FromFile(fileName);  
        int imgHeight = 100;  
        int imgWidth = 100;  
        if (img.Width < img.Height)  
        {  
            //portrait image  
            imgHeight = 100;  
            var imgRatio = (float) imgHeight / (float) img.Height;  
            imgWidth = Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * imgRatio);  
        }  
        else if(img.Height < img.Width)  
        {  
            //landscape image  
            imgWidth = 100;  
            var imgRatio = (float) imgWidth / (float) img.Width;  
            imgHeight = Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * imgRatio);  
        }  
        Image thumb = img.GetThumbnailImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);  
        thumb.Save(thumbName);  
         var imageupload = new imageupload();
         imageupload.ImageUplaod = thumbName;
         db.imageuploads.Add(imageupload);
         db.SaveChanges();

    }

    return View();  
   } catch (Exception ex)  
   {  
    ViewBag.Message = ex.Message.ToString();  
    return View();  
   }  
  }
```

**View**

```
 @model ImageUpload.Models.ImageUploadModels
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

  @using (Html.BeginForm("ImageUploadThumnail", "ImageUplaod", null,  FormMethod.Post, new
  {
   enctype = "multipart/form-data"
  })) {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
  <fieldset> <legend> Image </legend> 
  <div class = "editor-label" > 
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
     </div> 
  <div class = "editor-field"> 
    <input id = "ImagePath"  title = "Upload an image" type = "file" name = "file"/>
      </div> 
  <p> <input type = "submit" value = "Upload"/> 
     </p> 
 </fieldset>
  }
```

Now i posted two typesof upload what i tried . i want to know the difference between these two types and i want to know which is better to upload image in server after deploying the project. And also any one tell me how to create thumbnails for image using ajax . Here in above mention method i didn't use ajax for thumbnails . But i need to uplaod and save the path of the thumnails image using ajax. I tried my level best to explain my issue.Any one understand my issue and give me solution for this problem

Advance Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

> First of all any one explain me what is the difference between normal file uplaod and create thumbnail for image and save that path in db.

**What is a thumbnail image?**

It is just an image that looks like another image but with a smaller file size.

**Advantages of using thumbnails on web**

This can play a major role in web applications. When you visit a web page, like this one, if there are images on the page they need to be brought to your computer so your browser can show them to you. In other words, they need to be downloaded to your computer. Web sites developed with that in mind, will just include a low quality, small size image of the actual image and send that when you view the page. Then when you click on the image, for example, if you want to look at the image more closely, then the browser will make another request to the server and get the high quality image.

This technique makes the initial loading (downloading to be exact) fast so the user is not setting there waiting for all the big images if all they want to do is read something.

I am not sure if you are using `uploading` incorrectly but uploading is the opposite of downloading. When you visit a page, you are essentially downloading the page (unless you have already visited the page and the browser has cached it.) Therefore, uploading is you sending something to the server and I am not sure how sending something to the server will benefit from thumbnails.

I think what you may be speaking of is having a thumbnail image and the path to the high quality image of the thumbnail is stored in the db with thumbnail data. You send the thumbnail when someone requests it, then if they want the higher quality image, you get the path from the database and serve the high quality image.

This technique is highly in use by commerce sites. For example, when you are browsing Amazon, eBay, car dealerships the little images are low quality but enough to give you a good idea of what the product is. Once you click it, then the better quality images are retrieved.

**Advantages of using thumbnails in other type of applications**

Web is not the only place this can be used. I worked on an iPad application and we used the same technique. However, instead of clicking the image we were waiting to see if the user will zoom (pinch and zoom) on the image. As soon as the user zoomed in, we would get a higher quality image. If they zoomed in again, we would get even a higher quality image. We had 4 different levels of quality for each image.

In conclusion there are two advantages to using thumbnails:

1. Faster load (performance)
2. Bandwidth-smaller size images (especially important to mobile users because data will cost them $$$)

[Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00168328W) is a page with thumbnails. And [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008OYNK0G) are the better quality images of one of the thumbnails.